# delay in javascript onunload

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I am trying to trigger an event in Flex on onUnload, but the browser has to remain open and not kill flash for a few seconds until the information is sent.

Just need a few second delay. Is there anyway to do that without an alert?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have tried to creating flash Object again in routine called onunload and it worked.

Comment: OK. can you bother posting/sharing your code ? It will be a help for others too.